# How to get the config directory of a plugin in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

Is there a function like `$pluginsDir = sfConfig::get('sf_config_dir');` (which returns configuration directory for overall) to get directory of the specific plugin.
Lets say I have directory structure something like:

```
project/
       config/
       plugins/
              myplugin/
                      config/
```

I want to get output `/home/user_name/public_html/project/plugins/myplugin/config/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Symfony is shipped with a `sf_plugins_dir` which goes to `/home/user_name/public_html/project/plugins` but that's all.

Solutions (which are almost the same) are :

**1. build the path based on this config variable:**

```
sfConfig::get('sf_plugins_dir').DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'myplugin'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'config';
```

**2. give it as myplugin config**

In `myplugin/config/app.yml`:

```
all:
  myplugin:
    config_dir: %SF_PLUGINS_DIR%/myplugin/config
```

Then:

```
sfConfig::get('app_myplugin_config_dir');
```

Comment: I did knew about this @j0k I was hoping if there are any built-in functions for this

Comment: Should probably add a `recursive: true` entry under the `myplugin:` header for opt #2.